# $a^n$ even implies $a$ even

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing, divisibility

I've tried to prove that $(\forall a,n>0 \in \mathbb{N}),(a^n \text{ even} \implies a \text{ even})$, can someone tell me whether my proof is sound?

Lemma 1: $a \text{ even} \implies a^2 \text{ even}$

Lemma 2: $a \text{ odd} \implies a^2 \text{ odd}$

$$a^n \text{ even} \equiv a^{n-1}a \text{ even} \equiv (a^{n-1} \text{ odd} \land a \text{ even}) \lor (a^{n-1} \text{ even} \land a \text{ odd}) \lor (a^{n-1} \text{ even} \land a \text{ even})$$

by virtue of Lemma 1 (by construction) $(a \text{ even} \implies a^{n-1} \text{ even})$ and by the same argument, from Lemma 2, $(a \text{ odd} \implies a^{n-1} \text{ odd})$

whence, $(a^{n-1} \text{ odd} \land a \text{ even}) \equiv \text{False}$ and $(a^{n-1} \text{ even} \land a \text{ odd}) \equiv \text{False}$

therefore, we can write
$a^n \text{ even} \equiv F \lor F \lor (a^{n-1} \text{ even} \land a \text{ even}) \equiv (a^{n-1} \text{ even} \land a \text{ even})$

Since, $(\text{True} \equiv a^n \text{ even} \equiv (a^{n-1} \text{ even} \land a \text{ even})) \therefore a^{n-1} \text{ even and a even} \square$

Comment: Seems really convoluted when it's simple to prove $(2\lambda)^n = 2^n\lambda^n$ is even and $(2\lambda + 1)^n = \left(\sum_1^{n} 2^i\binom{n}{i}\lambda^i\right) + 1^n = 2\left(\sum_1^{n} 2^{i-1}\binom{n}{i}\lambda^i\right) + 1$ by the binomial theorem which means it's definitely of the form $2\eta  + 1$.

Comment: I think you wrote an even instead of odd in the 5th line, where you have $\lor$ etc..

Comment: As @Jared states, your proof is very complex for something very simple. You have logic as a section, you reffer that you want a proof using logical statements?

Comment: **Hint** $ $  contrapositively it is equivalent to: $\,a\,$ odd $\,\Rightarrow a^n$ odd, which follows easily by induction since $\,a^{n+1}\! = a(a^n) = $ odd $\times $ odd $\,=\,$ odd. $\ \ $

Comment: Hint: if you know [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) then use it for the prime $2$ and the product $a^n = a * a * ... * a$.

Comment: There is a proper way to inculde text within MathJax.  Your way of doing it made it look as if you assumed, not that the way you did it was the right way, but that there isn't any right way.  See my edits. $\qquad$

Comment: $$a^{m+1}-a=a(a^m-1)$$ which is divisible by $a(a-1)$ which is always even for integer $a$  $$\implies a^{m+1}\equiv a\pmod2$$

Comment: Even if you want a "logical" proof your lemmas need to be proved to be true.  Are you saying that's what you are "being given", in a sense, and then prove it from those statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is almost valid, but it is unfortunately circular, because you use the following lemma:

$$a \text{ is odd} \implies a^{n-1} \text{ is odd}$$
However, if you take the contrapositive of this statement:
$$a^{n-1} \text{ is even} \implies a \text{ is even}$$
which is basically the same as your statement, except with $n-1$ instead of $n$.

Therefore, in order to make your proof valid, **you need to pose it as a proof by induction**, making $n=1$ your base case and then using the proof you have written above to show that $a^{n-1} \text{ is even} \implies a \text{ is even}$ can be used to prove $a^n \text{ is even} \implies a \text{ is even}$.

Comment: By induction? I can see induction being used to prove $a ~ even \implies a^n ~ even$, but for the converse $a^n ~ even \implies a ~ even$ I don't see how you would use induction. What I can see from your answer is the possible overkill in the proof, since I know $a ~ odd \implies a^2 ~ odd$ and by induction $a ~ odd \implies a^n ~odd$, where the contrapositive is what I am trying to prove.

Comment: @MrRed Your whole proof was definitely overkill, but unless you want to completely overwrite it, you pretty much have to use induction. To use induction, first, prove the base case of $a \text{ is even} \implies a \text{ is even}$ and second, using the fact that $a^{n-1} \text{ is even} \implies a \text{ is even}$, prove that $a^n \text{ is even} \implies a \text{ is even}$. The first part should be easy and the second part is already done, as shown in your question above, so **you've already done almost all of the work**. All you need to do is adjust it so it's a valid induction argument.

Answer (score 1):

much better to prove the contrapositive

$a$ odd implies $a^n$ odd.

This is easily proved by induction since the product of two odd numbers is odd.

Answer (score 0):

What do you know about primes? If a prime divides a product, it divides one of the factors. You know 2 divides $a^n$, so what can you conclude?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't understand your problem.  Either the "lemmas" need to be proven to be true (which is very possible) or they prove your statement almost trivially--maybe that's your question.

There are two predicates here:

1. $p$: $a$ is odd/even
2. $q$: $a^2$ is odd/even

Thus your lemmas are the following (let's assume "even" means "true" and "odd" means "false"):

Lemma 1: If $a$ is even (p) then $a^2$ is even (q)
$$
p \rightarrow q
$$

Lemma 2: If $a$ is not even ($\neg p$) then $a^2$ is not even ($\neg q$)
$$
\neg p \rightarrow \neg q
$$

Your assumption (the two lemmas) assumes the conclusion.  It's apparent from my formulation that you are trying to prove:

$$
p \leftrightarrow q
$$

This statement is true if both of your lemmas are true--but I would question how we know those lemmas to be true to be able to prove this statement.